# failed features: failed to get reply for: [id: 6, method: Page.navigate, params: {url=https://github.com/login}]

Tags: karate

I am trying to setup karate for UI automation on Windows Laptop. I tried to run the sample code on the zip release 0.9.5 this is what I get.
failed features:

```
src.demo.web.google: google.feature:10 - failed to get reply for: [id: 6, method: Page.navigate, params: {url=https://github.com/login}]
```

the full stack trace is

```
feature: src/demo/web/google.feature:7  
report: target\surefire-reports\src.demo.web.google.json
scenarios:  1 | passed:  0 | failed:  1 
| time: 19.1133
---------------------------------------------------------
Karate version: 0.9.5
======================================================
elapsed:  20.17 | threads:    1 | thread time: 19.11
features:     1 | ignored:    0 | efficiency: 0.95
scenarios:    1 | passed:     0 | failed: 1
======================================================
```

failed features:

```
src.demo.web.google: google.feature:10 - failed to get reply for: [id: 6, method: Page.navigate, params: {url=https://github.com/login}]

18:43:56.084 [chrome_1595954616565] WARN  com.intuit.karate.shell.Command - exit code was non-zero: 1 - [C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe, --remote-debugging-port=9222, --no-first-run, --user-data-dir=C:\Users\Paul\Downloads\karate-0.9.5\target\chrome_1595954616565, --disable-popup-blocking] 
com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: there are test failures !
        at ...(.)
The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command java -cp karate.jar com.intuit.karate.Main "c:\Users\Downloads\karate-0.9.5\src\demo\web\google.feature:7"" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

Please how do I over come this.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Nearly impossible to troubleshoot given this level of information. So I suggest you follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Else here are my guesses:

- maybe Chrome is not installed in the "usual" place, read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#configure-driver
- maybe your laptop has some extra security settings, so ports are blocked, try to work with some tech support. try running `cmd.exe` as an "Administrator"
- try switching the browser / driver, again, read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#configure-driver
- don't use PowerShell - use `cmd` instead. see these docs also: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Karate-Robot-Windows-Install-Guide#install-visual-studio-code

That's all I can offer, the rest is up to you (or other stack overflow users) all the best.